# django is adding characters to my URL

Tags: django, url

When people visit my website, django is sometimes randomly adding characters to my URL. (It happens intermittently)

name_of_url.com gets re-routed to something like name_of_url.com/KiRkZ/

name_of_url.com/section gets re-routed to something like name_of_url.com/KiRkZ/section

Is there a way to remove these characters? It is causing a 404 error for the visitors it happens to.

It looks like it usually happens when it is being redirected from http to https (this is handled by godaddy forwarding). Every so often one of the redirects results in a 302 and adds the characters to the url, the rest of the time it results in a 301 and works fine

Comment: add `views.py` and also `urls.py`

Comment: is there something more specific you can ask for? I can't really provide the full views.py and urls.py. If there's any known issues that you know of that could be causing this, that would be super helpful too.